# Solr cell avoid metadata in fmap.content

Tags: solr, apache-tika, solr-cell

I am using Solr Cell for content extraction from PDFs. I am storing extracted content of the PDFs in field named content. `<str name= "fmap.content">content</str>`. And inside this field I also get metadata in addition to the content itself, that I don't need.

For example: `\n date 2020-11-11T11:04:50Z  \n pdf:PDFVersion 1.4 \n stream_content_type application/pdf  \n pdf:hasXFA false` 
How can I avoid this?